# How to change the Android Emulator's IP address on virtualbox?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

How to change the Android Emulator's IP address on virtualbox?
I couldn't get emulator's ip.
I was  type this code:
[image]

but there is no emulator's ip?

I hope somoeone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: The virtual machine should request an IP address through DHCP. What is the virtual network configuration of the guest? Please include both the adapter type and the mode - probably NAT - it is set to. Also, what does `ifconfig` show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is impossible to change IP address of emulator. Each emulator is in
>   one private network. The ip address 10.0.2.15 is only the private
>   network, and host identify each emulator with one different port from
>   others.
>
> For example, you turn on 2 emulator, then host will connect to
>   emulator 1 with port 5554, to emulator 2 with port 5555. These 2
>   emulator still has its IP address 10.0.2.15

Comment: thanks!  but don't connect to emulyator. I was type this code :  ./adb connect 10.0.2.15
unable to connect to 10.0.2.15:5555

Comment: try this . adb shell
ifconfig eth0

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to set your network to Bridged Adapter.  This should give your emulator a dhcp address from your router, so it will exist on the same network as your dev box.